# EntityDataSource losing WHERE statement after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entitydatasource

I have a GridView bound to this EntityDataSource:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="lotDetailQuery" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
    ConnectionString="name=encoreEntities" DefaultContainerName="encoreEntities"
    EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="lotdetails" Include="lot, lot.salesorder" 
    Where="false" OrderBy="it.lotdetaildate">           
    <WhereParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderNum" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="BoxNum" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SerialNum" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="InvoiceNum" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="DateFrom" ControlID="txtDateFrom" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DateTo" Type="DateTime" />
    </WhereParameters>   
</asp:EntityDataSource></asp:Content>
```

In the codebehind, I set the values of the WhereParameters and the Where statement.  (For example, if the user searches for BoxNum JLS001, then then Where statement is set to "it.boxnum = @BoxNum" and the WhereParam BoxNum is set to JLS001.  The gridview works fine when the user is searching.

The problem comes in when the user deletes one of the records, using a Delete button I provided.  After the deletion, I try to refresh the gridview with GridView.DataBind().  When the postback finishes, the gridview is empty.

I found that, while the WhereParameters survived the postback (BoxNum is still set to JLS001), the Where statement did not.  After postback, this statement is set to "false" as it was when the page originally loaded.

Aside from a kludge like writing the Where statement into an invisible label and then copying it into the EntityDataSource, is there a way to preserve the value of the Where statement during postback?

Or maybe there is a better way to use dynamic queries with EntityFramework.  I am accustomed to using SqlDataSources and attaching them to stored procedures and passing parameters and that worked just fine this way.  The logic for the SQL query to query the correct tables resided in the stored procedure, though.  Here, the logic is in my codebehind.

Comment: You can set where statement and parameters by code http://nothingbutcode.blogspot.com/2011/07/programmatically-set-where-clause-of.html

Comment: I do set them in the code behind the first time the user clicks a search button.  After the gridview is modified, I want it to simply be updated using the same where statement and params, but the where statement does not survive the postback.  I don't want to rebuild it on every postback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, short of another solution, here's what I ended up doing - I added an invisible label to the page to hold the Where statement.  During GridView databinding, I write the value there:

```
lblunitQueryWhere.Text = unitQuery.Where;
```

And in Page_Load, I read it from there and update the GridView's datasource:

```
if (IsPostBack)
            unitQuery.Where = lblunitQueryWhere.Text;
```

Doing it this way, I can preserve the Where across postbacks.